# Add SLComposeServiceViewController on top of View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to present a `SLComposeServiceViewController` on top of my existing view controller which is a navigation controller that contains a map. When I present the `SLComposeServiceViewController` it has a black background and overlays it over my existing view.

The code I am using is:

```
SLComposeServiceViewController *composeVC = [[SLComposeServiceViewController alloc]init];

composeVC.placeholder = @"Enter your post";
[self presentViewController:composeVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here is an example of what I am seeing

[image]

How can I show the view on top of my existing view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  SLComposeServiceViewController *composeVC = [[SLComposeServiceViewController alloc]init];

composeVC.placeholder = @"Enter your post";
composeVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyleOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:composeVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```